# Redis Replication INFO command return wrong replication information

Tags: redis, nat, master-slave, redis-sentinel

I have 1 master Redis and 2 slave nodes.

Deployment in done on environment which does NAT and assign dynamic host and port to nodes.

I have virtual IP/Port created for master which is mentioned in slave nodes configuration file

```
replicaof <master vip> <master vip port>
```

When I connect master and query [INFO](https://redis.io/commands/info/#:%7E:text=The%20INFO%20command%20returns%20information,clients%20%3A%20Client%20connections%20section) command,

Returned result is something like below

```
INFO replication
# Replication
role:master
connected_slaves:2
slave0:ip=<master vip>,port=<master vip port>    ------> Incorrect
slave1:ip=<master vip>,port=<master vip port>    ------> Incorrect
```

I am unable to understand why [INFO](https://redis.io/commands/info/#:%7E:text=The%20INFO%20command%20returns%20information,clients%20%3A%20Client%20connections%20section) return master IP and Port as slave IP and Port in this case. It should return IP and port of the machine which is running slaves nodes.

Thank in advance.